# Android - Correct placement of listeners with ExpandableListAdapter

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-adapter

I have a class named **ExpandableListAdapter** which extends BaseExpandableListAdapter. My getChildView method looks like this:

```
    @Override
   public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView,
        ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }

    tv_questionAmountResult = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_questionAmountResult);
    tv_correctAmountResult = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_correctAmountResult);
    tv_wrongAmountResult = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_wrongAmountResult);

    bt_allQuestions = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bt_allQuestions);
    bt_correctQuestions = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bt_correctQuestions);
    bt_wrongQuestions = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bt_wrongQuestions);

    return convertView;
}
```

My Other class **ActTraining** is using the ExpandableListAdapter within the onCreate method:

```
 ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
 ExpandableListView expListView;

    // get the listview
    expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.topicExpandableListView);

    // preparing list data
    prepareListData();

    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

    // setting list adapter
    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

Now I want to add OnClickListener for the 3 buttons, but I'm not sure with the correct placement.
Do I have to add the listeners in my getChildView or in my ActTraining class?

Answer (score 0):

You must put `OnClickListener` in your `ExpandableListAdapter.getChildView` for all 3 buttons because you have their buttons in every childItem.

some useful link for handle `OnClickListener`:

[RecyclerView click listener](http://alexzh.com/tutorials/recyclerview-click-listener/)

[Set a click listener to a RecyclerView](http://antonioleiva.com/recyclerview-listener/)

Comment: The problem is that my ExpandableListAdapter doesn't extend Activity. So I can't use for example startActivity().

Comment: you can make a `callback` method and put it into an interface and call it in your `onClickListener` and then implement callback in your activity. I edited the answer and add some useful link.